# php how to create a dropdown select input of all table from a database?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

for example, I have a database named "school", and it contains 3 tables "teacher", "student" and "staff".
I wanna create one form with one select input with option of all 3 tables, and you can choose any of these 3 tables to insert data into.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get all table name from database try this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbName'
```

Note: Use [select2](https://select2.org/) library or other library for multi-pick list.